# passing JavaScript array of long to code behind?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, arrays, activex, object

I have returned object from signature device and when i make quick watch on it, it told me that its an array of long and when i pass it to web method in my code behind (vb.net) it gives me nothing. 
i need some help..
note: i'm using an activeX to capture the signature from the device.

this is javascript code :

```
function OnSave() {
    var sign = document.FORM1.SigPlus1.SignatureString;
    PageMethods.Save(sign);
    }
```

this is my webmethod:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function Save(ByVal obj As Object) As String

    Dim obj1 As New PFSIGNATURELib.SigniShellSignature
    obj1.SignatureMime = obj
    obj1.SaveBitmapToFile(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory() & "\sign1.bmp", 200, 200)

    Return "\sign1.bmp"
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about ASP.Net, but it seems like the `PageMethods.Save` function can't handle an array of long. Another possibility is that the `sign` variable is null in the javascript code.

Try adding

```
alert(sign);
```

in the middle your Javascript function, or better yet, install firebug and do

```
console.log(sign);
```

instead. This way you'll make sure the sign var actually contains what you think it does.

If it indeed contains an array of numbers (javascript doesn't have a `long` type), maybe you need to convert it to something else before calling the `PageMethods.Save` function.

For example, this javascript snippet will convert `sign` into a space-separated string of numbers:

```
s = ""
for (i in sign) {
    s += sign[i] + " ";
}
sign = s
```

If you manage to pass this string to your webmethod, you can use some string parsing to get back the original array.